# How to randomly convert some 1's to 0's in an array

Tags: python

I have a numpy array of a certain length full of 1's and 0's and, of all the 1's I have, I'd like to convert a certain proportion of them to 0's. I need to maintain the rest of them at their proper position.

I can of-course run a for loop to do so, but I wonder if there's anything better. Thanks.

Here's what I tried to do. It has two problems.

1) doesn't work

2) the 1's aren't replaced randomly. I need to collect indices somehow to be able to do that but I do not know how to

```
x = np.array([1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1])
print(x)
for i in np.nditer(x,op_flags=['readwrite']):
    if i ==1 & sum(x)>2:
        i[...] = 0 #np.random.binomial(1,0)

print(x)
```

Note: If there are 30 1's, I want to be able to specify exactly how many of the 30 will become zero (say 14). But then, those 14 should be chosen randomly from the 30 and assigned a value of zero.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you haven't demonstrated any attempt to solve this problem yourself. Write some code that attempts to solve the problem and if there is a clear issue with the code not working as expected, try asking again.

Comment: Sorry, updated. I just couldn't get anything to do what i wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use logical indexing for fast results:

```
>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1.])
>>> a_orig = a.copy()

>>> a[a!=0] = np.random.rand(a.sum())
>>> a[a>0.5] = 1
>>> a[a<=0.5] = 0

>>> a_orig
array([ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.])

>>> a
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.])
```

Zeros have been preserved, some ones have changed.

Remark that I forced the datatype (dtype) of the original array to be of type 'float'. However, if it's 'int8' or variants, you can use `np.random.randint(0,2, a.sum())` instead of `np.random.rand(a.sum())` and the 2 subsequent lines.

Edit: with your *revised post*, detailing you want a *specific amount of ones to flip*, you could use `np.random.shuffle`, as shown below:

```
>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
>>> a_orig = a.copy()
>>> how_many_flip = 4  # you'll have to make sure it's less than a.sum()

>>> b = np.hstack((np.zeros(how_many_flip, dtype=int), np.ones(a.sum()-how_many_flip, dtype=int)))
>>> np.random.shuffle(b)
>>> b
array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0])
>>> a[a!=0] = b
>>> a
array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
>>> a_orig
array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added a note. I wanted to be able to specify how many of them are changed exactly. I think this doesn't let me do that.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly. If you can make your question more specific, always do that from the first time you post. ;-)

Comment: Very nice solutions to both versions, @Oliver W. I realized I had a similar problem recently and came up with a much uglier one.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done

```
a = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
a[2:4]=[0]*2

>>> a
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array is sorted, you can find the boundary between the 0's and 1's using a binary search (which will happen in O(log n) time). Once you have the boundary, set a proportional amount of 1's to 0 - which you should be able to implement in constant time (O(1)).

If the array is unsorted, the best you will be able to do is linear time (O(n)).